# SQL get minimum date out of all groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Column A: text
Column B: datetime
Column C: text
```

`Column A` has three possible values: **ADD, DELETE, OTH**

What I am trying to do is to group the records by `Column C`, and get the minimum datetime **IF** `Column A` is either **ADD or OTH**

For example, if the table is

```
A         B          C
DELETE    2013-Jul   ABC
ADD       2014-Jul   DEF
OTH       2015-Jul   ABC
OTH       2016-Jul   DEF
ADD       2017-Jul   ABC
```

I want to get something like

```
Group      Min_Date    Type
ABC        2015-Jul    OTH
DEF        2014-Jul    ADD
```

Is it possible to do it by GROUP or PARTITION? 
Any hints is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregate function

```
select C,min(B) as Min_Date from tabl1
where A in ('OTH','ADD')
group by C
```

As OP is recent changed output,so use below query

```
select distinct * from t where B in ( select min(B) from t t1 
                            where t1.C=t.c
                           and  t1.A in ('OTH','ADD')
                                    )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/57770/15

```
a     b          c
ADD 2014-07-01  DEF
OTH 2015-07-01  ABC
```

Comment: Thanks! How about if I want to know the corresponding Column A as well? (Sorry I missed it in the OP, will edit it now)

Comment: then put A as well in group by

Comment: Then it will get the minimum B of each A, instead of minimum across all (OTH, ADD)?

Comment: edit your expected output i think over clause need to apply

Comment: @shole check the answer please

Comment: Thanks, I accpet you as I think it is the correct direction! Is it possible to handle the tie case? Say if there is one more row for (DEF, OTH, 2014-Jul), so there is two minimum date for DEF, in such case I want to always choose "OTH" as the only return, can it be done?